# Archive without root folder in .zip [node-archiver]

Tags: javascript, node.js, archive, node-archiver

I'm using node-archiver to archive folder "export" with photos inside.

Everything works ok but inside archive I got folder 'offers' and photos are in this folder.

I would like to have like a "flat" .zip, so when I'll unpack my .zip it unpack photos without that 'offers' folder.

My code:

```
  const folderPath = '/export/.';
  const output = fs.createWriteStream('test/offers.zip');
  const archive = archiver('zip');
  archive.pipe(output);
  archive.directory(folderPath, false);
  archive.finalize();
```

What I'm getting after unpacking:

[image: image1]

What I would like to get:

[image: image2]

How can I achieve this?

Regards,
Gemmi

Comment: I think that's because `/export/.` is the same as `/export` so it targets the folder, not the files inside. Try changing the path to `/export/*`

Comment: Hi @Seblor, thx. I already tried that and with `*` node-archiver won't zipping my files.

Comment: Have you tried `archive.directory( 'export/' , false);` or `archive.glob( 'export/*.*' );` ?

Comment: Oh right, I forgot it should be `.glob` not `.directory`, my bad. Good catch Shilly

Comment: Thank you for replay @Shilly It doesn't work in any provided examples :/

Answer (score 2):

All you need is set prefix via options property. 
Like this

```
archive.directory(folderPath, false, { prefix: 'your destination folder' });
```

Regards,
Lukas